# Displaying survey results using group_concate in mysql segregated by category

Tags: mysql, survey

In my Mysql database I have a table named 'survey'. This table is used to record survey data. the Table structure is shown below. The survey is conducted in different cities whose count is above 100.

TABLE NAME : Survey

```
ID        options      user_ID   City 
----------------------------------------------
1         option1        101     City1
2         option2        102     City2
3         option3        103     City1
4         option1        104     City3
5         option1        105     City1
6         option2        106     City2
7         option3        107     City1
So on....
------------------------------------------------
```

I want to list all user_ids which choose a particular option segregated on city basis. Like

```
city1
--------------------------------------------
option1  list of user_ids
option2  list of user_ids
option3  list of user_ids

city2
--------------------------------------------
option1  list of user_ids
option2  list of user_ids
option3  list of user_ids 
--------------------------------------

so on.......
```

If I ran this query

```
SELECT OPTIONS,
       GROUP_CONCAT(user_id ORDER BY user_id ASC SEPARATOR ' | ' )
  FROM survey WHERE city= 'city1'
 GROUP BY options  ;
```

I get What I want but for city1 one only. How can I extend it to get a list for all the  cities, Please help thank you.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: How can I achive this in PHP. Can you give me some link of tutorial or any keyword that I can google, You see I am still learning PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the city in your select statement instead of in where, like this:

```
SELECT city,
       OPTIONS,
       GROUP_CONCAT(user_id ORDER BY user_id ASC SEPARATOR ' | ' )
  FROM survey 
 GROUP BY city, options;
```

This will result in:

```
city1 option1  list of user_ids
city1 option2  list of user_ids
city1 option3  list of user_ids
city2 option1  list of user_ids
city2 option2  list of user_ids
city2 option3  list of user_ids
```

You can also order it as you please adding at the end: `order by options, city` or `order by city, options`

Comment: Hey thanks jorge. But instead of repeating city values in each rows cant it be possible that city appears only once.

Comment: Yes, but it will be a little bit more complicated. Will update the query later as I'm not home. The better approach for that however would be to handle that in the application level.